# CUPS as a single printer for network pdf printing

Tags: pdf, network-printer, cups

I have some equipment which has the option to print the results of a run, to a networked printer; however the only option provided to configure the printer is IP/port.

Presumably this is OK if there's an actual printer to print to - but I'd like the output to go to a PDF printer (I've got cups-pdf set up, but could easily use some other software). If I try to print a test page from the machine, I see the following error message in the CUPS logsfile:

```
Unable to encrypt connection from 192.168.15.101 - A record packet with illegal version was received
```

I think that the security error may be because the print request is being sent to the root of 192.168.15.100:631, rather than to /printers/pdf, although I've also read about there being an unresolvable bug in the current version of gnutls?

Unless there's a way to set up CUPS with a dedicated port for a particular printer, perhaps the first thing to try would be to set up a listener on a port (e.g. 192.168.15.100:632) on which all traffic is sent to 127.0.0.1:631/printers/pdf. Is there a simple way to do this using xinetd or similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the printer is expecting to send to a single port, it may be expecting and `lpr` type setup.  Try configuring the CUPS BSD printer components.  Port 515 is default printer spooler port.